# Office365 outlook add in - Get tenant programmatically

Tags: javascript, azure, outlook, office-addins

I'm currently in the process of developing an outlook add-in. So far, I've got everything working, and the add-in works perfectly on MY tenant. The problem is that I don't know how to get the tenant programmatically (so the add-in will dynamically get tenant `TestTenant` instead of hardcoding MY tenant `DummyTenant`).

**Home.js**

```
baseEndpoint = 'https://' + tenant + '.sharepoint.com/';
```

This is my variable `baseEndpoint`. Notice the tenant, this comes straight from the `Config.js`

**Config.js**

```
var tenant = 'radoorworkpoint';
```

If anyone know how to do this, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Office Discovery Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations)? This should allow you to retrieve the tenant the user is on.